# In Python, can an object become hashable after it is created?

Tags: python

I want to create recursive data structures via a class Wrapper, and I want to be able to do something like this:

```
A = Wrapper()

A.assign_value((A, 5))

my_set = set()
my_set.add(A)
```

This requires A to be hashable, but one of the requirements is (according to docs):

> it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime

The Wrapper object can **become** hashable, and then used freely in sets and as dictionary keys, so long as `assign_value` can only be used once, but I'm not sure if that meets the definition, since the value changes over its lifetime (even though the value is guaranteed not to change any more). Also, I'm unsure how I would implement a `__hash__` function that sometimes indicates "this object is not actually hashable", if it's even possible. It seems the very existence of a valid `__hash__` function indicates that an object is hashable, regardless of what it returns when called, in standard Python.

My current idea is to set the `__hash__` function in the instance rather than the class, like this:

```
class Wrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.assigned = False

    def _hash(self):
        return hash(Wrapper, self.val)

    def _eq(self, a):
        if isinstance(self, Wrapper) and a.assigned:
            return self.val == a.val
        return NotImplemented

    def assign_value(self, val):
        if self.assigned == True:
            raise NotImplementedError()
        self.assigned = True
        self.val = val
        self.__hash__ = self._hash
        self.__eq__ = self._eq
```

I am realizing that the hash function will enter an infinite loop, constantly trying to compute `hash(A)`, in my given example. `__eq__` will also face this problem, though in that case it can be resolved the same way recursive lists are handled in Python. Setting a default hash value (like `hash(Wrapper)`) to be used in the computation for Wrapper objects does seem to fix the infinite recursion problem in theory though, making the whole thing still technically possible. I could also just say `def _hash(self): return 0`, despite the performance cost for sets and dicts.

Would this work as I expect? Is it the best way to do this? Most importantly, **should** I be doing this in the first place?

Comment: I think you should give some thought as to why you need a gap between initializing the `Wrapper` instance and actually setting the value, rather than just waiting until you would call `Wrapper.assign_value` to actually create the `Wrapper` instance.

Comment: @chepner The value contains the wrapper instance, therefore the wrapper instance must exist before assign_value is called on the value. Would something like lambda A: (A, 5) be the argument to __init__, which then creates A and also assigns the value using the lambda at the same time?